# measuring elapsed seconds using chrono (stop watch) C++

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, measure

I am currently trying to create a way to display the elapsed seconds (not the difference between cycles). My code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TIME;
#define TIMENOW() std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
#define TIMECAST(x) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(x).count()

int main()
{
std::chrono::duration<double>  ms;
double t = 0;
while (1)
{

 TIME begin = TIMENOW();
 int c = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
 {
     c += i*100000; 
 }
 TIME end = TIMENOW();

 ms= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(end - begin);
 
 t =t+ ms.count();
  std::cout << t << std::endl;

 }
```

I expected adding the delta time over and over again to roughly give me the elapsed time in seconds, however I noticed that only if I do `i < big number` it sort of is fairly accurate. If its only 10,000 or so, t seems to accumulate slower and gradually faster. Maybe I am missing something but isnt the difference my delta time(the elapsed time between this and last cycle) and if I keep adding the delta times up, it should spit out seconds? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running it in a multiprocess environment (like typical Windows, Linux, etc.)?

Comment: Several mistakes in this code.  `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` does not reliably measure elapsed time.  Your `for` loop can be completely removed by the C++ optimizer, since the loop has no observable effect.  Casting an integer duration to a double duration can only lose accuracy.  Signed integer overflow also makes this program exhibit Undefined Behavior.

Comment: You could  substantially better elaborate this by providing an example of the output your getting vs. something akin to the output you're *expecting*, and the difference between the two that causes your confusion. The code provided should accumulate the elapsed time of what is sandwiched between `begin` and `end`, which is only a fraction of the overall wall-clock time spent executing this code. Just the IO to stdout will eat a non-trivial amount of wall-clock time. And finally, release-optimizing this will literally throw out the for-loop, making the measurement pointless to begin with.

Comment: `std::chrono::duration<double>  ms;` That variable name will result in confusion. You're using a duration with ratio 1 : 1, i.e. seconds, but the name suggests a ratio of 1 : 1000

Comment: Also note that there's no real need to use macros here and even the typedef is unnecessary: `auto TIMENOW() { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); } ... auto const begin = TIMENOW(); ... auto const end = TIMENOW(); ... using namespace std::chrono_literals; t += (end - start) / 1ms;` Not using macros is preferrable, since functions are namespace/overload aware and won't just apply to everything that looks like a function call. Btw: note that there's nothing preventing the compiler from completely optimizing out the for loop.

Comment: Time meaningless code, get meaningless timing. What real-world quantify are you trying to measure?